# ruby: Using local variable in methods

Tags: ruby, variables, methods

I have a local variable in my main program. Now i would llike to give it to a method so it can use it for it's work.
What is the best way to do it? A Instance variable @test?

Comment: Learn about `Scope` from [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Scope) with example

Answer (score 1):

You can give that variable as a method parameter, as shown in the example below:

```
def main_program
  my_variable = 3
  other_method(my_variable)
end

def other_method(special_variable)
  # do something with the special-variable
end
```

A nice read on how to define and call methods can be found in the [Ruby programming wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls)

Comment: Can i also give two variables? Like other_method(var1)(var2)?

Comment: @saigkill yes, you can, `other_method(var1, var2)`. I advice you to start from some basics before you start programming in Ruby.

Comment: @saigkill Marek is right. I've updated my answer with a link explaining methods in ruby. I hope that helps :)